# how to extend ListView. basic example ClassNotFoundExcpetion android.view.MyListView at dalvik.system

Tags: android, listview, noclassdeffounderror, extends

I want to extend ListView but I do not understand what am I doing wrong. Here is my code, very simple and basic:

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TrymylistviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<MyListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

TrymylistviewActivity.java

```
package com.my.test;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TrymylistviewActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

MyListView.java

```
package com.my.test;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MyListView extends ListView {

public MyListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

    }
```

If I use ListView instead of myListView in res/layout/main.xml the app runs in the emulator. But of course if I extend ListView with MListview then I want to use it. What am I doing wrong?

this is the beginning and the interesting part of the stack-trace.

```
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{com.my.test/com.my.test.TrymylistviewActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class MyListView
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)... 11 more
....
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   android.view.MyListView
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
....
06-08 22:51:33.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use your own namespace:

```
    <MyListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

should be:

```
    <com.my.test.MyListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: thank you. I knew it was a silly mistake, but I couldn't figure it out by myself, and had an hard time finding answers. Hope it helps somebody else. I can accept your answer in 10 minutes! you were very quick! EDIT: for the sake of completeness, when extending a listview or anything all the constructors have to be implemented, and must use your own namespace the reference the class. got it! :)